# Android If CheckBox checked show Button dont work

Tags: android, sqlite, button, dynamic, checkbox

I have worked for a long time on this problem.
I want to show a Button if CheckBox is checked. I have CheckBoxes in number of columns in my DataBase. And If the Checkbox is unchecked i want to hide this Button. 
I see in this Forum this way, but it wasnt work right in my program.

```
        btn.setVisibility(View.GONE); 
        btn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

And my program shows:

```
    private void AddColum(int count) {
    final LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.ListLayout);
    for(int i=1; i<=count; i++) {
        final int id_ = createCheckBox(i, ll);
        CheckBox checkbox = (CheckBox) findViewById(id_);
        final IsCheck check = new IsCheck();
        checkbox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Button open = createButton(id_,ll);
                    if (check.getCheck()) {
                        open.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        open.setText("Ac");
                        open.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(View view) {
                                Intent myIntent = new Intent(ListActivity.this, ShowActivity.class);
                                myIntent.putExtra("ID", id_);
                                ListActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);

                            }
                        });
                        check.setCheck(false);
                    } else {
                        open.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        check.setCheck(true);
                    }
                }
        });
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

For Checking checkbox check and uncheck state you should use :

```
CheckBox check = findViewById(R.id.sprint_checkbox);
check.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {      
        if(isChecked){
                btn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);    
         }else{
                btn.setVisibility(View.GONE);    
         }

    }
});
```